# Using same database for main and subdomain

Tags: database, subdomains

I have a website let's say mysite.com (with it's own database that I created through plesk) and i have created a subdomain with the name sub.mysite.com.

After trying to install wordpress on my subdomain, I figured that I can't create a second database from Pesk as my hosting does no allow this through my subscription.

Can I use the same database that I use at mysite.com also to my subdomain, just creating a new database user, or I will destroy the current database?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use the same database that I use at mysite.com also to my subdomain

Yes, as long as the table names don't clash you're fine, some people have multiple WP instances using the same database, but with different table prefixes.

However, keep in mind that there is a security risk as now 2 sites have access to eachothers data.

> or I will destroy the current database?

If you run a destructive query yes! But why would you do that.

---

I don't think you have anything to fear here, but, it would be much easier to just create a local dev environment and test it out. This would give you the confidence and a practice run to do it in production